# How can I defer rendering a React component until webpack loads and applies a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader

I'm trying to figure out the best way to defer rendering a React component until react-scoped-css (I think it boils down to css-loader under the hood) imports and applies a sass module.

Right now I'm using polling to check document.styleSheets for the stylesheet. My code looks roughly like:

```
import './style.scoped.scss'
import { h, Component } from 'preact'

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.canRender = false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkRender()
  }

  checkRender() {
    // Mega hack
    this.canRender = [...document.styleSheets].some(x => {
      try {
        return x.rules && [...x.rules].some(y => y.selectorText && y.selectorText.startsWith('.my-component'))
      } catch {
        return false;
      }
    })

    if (!this.canRender) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.checkRender.bind(this))
    } else {
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.canRender && (
      <div>My component content</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Obviously this isn't ideal. Is it possible to use `import().then()` or listen for a JS event or similar to be notified when the stylesheet is applied so I can get rid of the polling?

Comment: What is these styles that you need to wait for? why?

Comment: The component I was working on did a layout measurement on load, and the styles modified the size. So if the styles loaded after the component, the measurement was invalid.

Comment: You should extract your styles into a separate css file, and load it via link tag, your issue will be solved, since the browser will block the render till styles are loaded